# Determine base revision from tag

Tags: svn

I have a tag with several changes on it whose base revision came from somewhere (branch? trunk? not sure.)  I believe what happened was I checked out the trunk, made changes to it, then tagged from my working copy.  I've tried to use the following command, but it doesn't say anything about the base.  What I want to do is find the base and do a comparison between the tag and the base revision to see what changes were made between the base and tag.

```
svn log -v --stop-on-copy (url)
```

results in:

```
r3678 | my.name | 2010-12-23 14:44:40 -0800 (Thu, 23 Dec 2010) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
   A /tags/dir
   A /tags/dir/subdir
   A /tags/dir/subdir/subsubdir

My commit message.
```

Comment: show real log, **not fake**. Where are *files*? or you have empty repo?!

Comment: That is a real log on windows.  The log shows 3 added directories.  There were no files changed in this commit (this is part of the reason I was confused).  I only changed my name and directory names, as it wasn't relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The container folder's log only shows the history for that folder.  I had to drill down to the actual source folder and look at its history to see where things were coming from.

As it turned out, I copied from the trunk to my user directory, did a bit of development there, and tagged from the user directory.

Answer (score 3):

You keep talking about the changes on the tag. However, tags should never<sup>1</sup> be modified. Tags should be completely immutable<sup>1</sup> and never modified by anyone<sup>1</sup>.

Anyway, if you looked at the tag's `svn log` message, you should be able to see the change there:

```
$ svn log -v --stop-on-copy (url)/tags/1.0

r3678 | my.name | 2010-12-23 14:44:40 -0800 (Thu, 23 Dec 2010) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
     A /tags/1.0 (from /trunk:2432)


My commit message.
```

And, if you aren't sure where you did this, you can simply do a `svn log` on the entire repository, and only look at the first few transactions since your change should be one of the first few changes.

---

<sup>1.</sup>In computers, *never* means sometimes in extreme circumstances. There will of course, come a time when you might have to modify a tag, but it should be very, very rare. For example, right after you just finished a tag, a developer comes and complains that they had to make one more change. Of course, you might simply be better off deleting the tag and recreating it.

I have a [pre-commit hook](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/newest_svn_hooks.zip) that allows users to create a tag, but prevents users from modifying a tag once it has been created. You can configure it to allow only admins to modify tags just in case you actually have to do just that.

Comment: Yes, tags should never be modified.  I misspoke there.  When I ran the svn log command on the correct directory, the 'from' bit did show up.